# Width and show issue when use highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm triyng to do a select that when change, show a different chart. There's 2 problems:

1-the chart don't show on all the div width.
2- How can I do for when 1 chart show, hide the others?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/)**

HTML

```
<div style="width:80%;">
<select class="selectchart" id="selectsolicitacoes"><option>Por mês</option><option value="#hg3">Por semana</option><option value="#hg2">Por dia</option></select><br>
<div id="hg2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none;">        </div>
<div id="hg3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; display: none;">     </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectsolicitacoes').change(function(){
    var element = $(this).val();
    $(element).show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your divs have incorrect width, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/10/ which introduce width of your divs.

```
div {
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

2) You can hide all divs and show only which you need http://jsfiddle.net/6S9cZ/11/